# How to show overlay text while filter is empty

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I need to show no results found message when user tries to filter any columns.

Is there any way to achieve it in AG-Grid?

```
[noRowsOverlayComponent]="noRowsOverlayComponent"
```

Find the example here. Try to enter any incorrect value for any columns.

http://plnkr.co/edit/FPiWCCBVs6UFHuVNa69b?p=preview

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you want to display `NoRowsOverlay` when there is not records in the grid.

Check this plunk I created: **[ag-grid Custom Overlay Components - when there are no rows to display](http://plnkr.co/edit/vD9ucdoaogHS01Bl2JYd?p=preview)**.
*Open this Plunk and try to filter first column with `zzz` string. You'll see it functioning when there are no records in the grid.*

#### How:

One way (of the many - I assume) is to do this is inside `onModelUpdated` event of [ag-grid](/questions/tagged/ag-grid).
When this event is fired, check whether are there any `rowsToDisplay` in the grid or not. Depending on that, you can decide if you want to display overlay or not.

```
onModelUpdated($event){
  if(this.gridApi && this.gridApi.rowModel.rowsToDisplay.length == 0) {
    this.gridApi.showNoRowsOverlay();
  }
  if(this.gridApi && this.gridApi.rowModel.rowsToDisplay.length > 0) {
    this.gridApi.hideOverlay();
  }
}
```

Comment: severity: 'Error'
message: 'Property 'rowModel' is private and only accessible within class 'GridApi'.'
at: '230,53'
source: 'ts'
code: '2341'

Comment: @SaurabhAgrawal you can ask question along with the code n information if you are facing any issue

Answer (score 4):

**2022 Edition**

```typescript
const baseOptions: GridOptions = {
  overlayNoRowsTemplate:
    '<span style="padding: 10px; border: 2px solid #444; background: lightgoldenrodyellow;">This is a custom \'no rows\' overlay</span>',
  onModelUpdated: (event: ModelUpdatedEvent) => {
    event.api.getDisplayedRowCount() === 0 ? 
        event.api.showNoRowsOverlay() : 
        event.api.hideOverlay();
  },
};
```